# Ran into a problem with the pymodbus library

Tags: python, pymodbus

> Name: pymodbus
> Version: 3.6.3
> Summary: A fully featured modbus protocol stack in python
> Home-page:
> Author: Galen Collins, Jan Iversen
> Author-email:
> License: BSD-3-Clause

The instruction I sent was：01 03 fa 0c 00 01 74 d1 should respond：01 03 00 02 13 8C E8 9F
The runner finds that the sending is correct, but the data of the response is missing a bit
The program sends instructions： b'\x01\x03\xfa\x0c\x00\x01t\xd1'（01 03 fa 0c 00 01 74 d1），Program response：b'\x01\x03\x00\x02\x13\x8c\xe8'（01 03 00 02 13 8C E8）
I've noticed that when it counts the number of bits of response data, it's one bit less. The correct one should be 8 bits, and it calculates 7 bits
Eventually returned：ModbusIOException('[Input/Output] No Response received from the remote slave/Unable to decode response')
I'm using serial access, and I make sure that all parameters are correct, such as baud rate. How can I fix it

```
self.client = ModbusSerialClient(port=port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)
   self.client.connect()
    result = self.client.read_holding_registers(slave=self.slave, address=starting_address)
```

Comment: Does adding the kwarg `strict=False` to `ModbusSerialClient` help?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and still have problems

Comment: You write "missing a bit" but do you actually mean; missing a byte?

Comment: Yes, the received data calculated by the program is 7 bits. And the actual data that my device responds to is 8 bits

Comment: Do you also experience problems when using e.g. [Modbus poll](https://www.modbustools.com/modbus_poll.html)?

Comment: I haven't tried this tool, but it's normal for me to use other tools